# Retry until with dynamic path or params

Tags: karate

I'm writing a test which is supposed to paginate through a large list of resources found on the server. I was hoping I could use `retry until` to account for the repeated requests, using a dynamic param as a way to advance through the pages.

Here's one of the variants I've tried:

```
    * configure headers = buildHeaders('token')
    * configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 200 }
    * def seen = []
    * def pageCount = 1

    Given path '/configs'
    And param size = 50
    And param page = pageCount
    And retry until response._links.next == null
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And def pageCount = pageCount + 1
    And seen.push(karate.map(response._embedded.configs, function(config){ return config.id }))
```

In the sample above, I am trying to get the `page` parameter change with each request. That doesn't work as I wanted to, as the `page` parameter remains 1 in every one of the 10 requests.

The question is: is there any way of doing this using `retry until` ?

Comment: hope you don't mind me closing as duplicate, but I think the linked answer is exactly the answer you are looking for. you can't, by design. but there are good alternatives.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Sorry for asking a duplicate. The other thread is identical to what I was asking.